# How to redirect to another Page using a button in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn how to redirect through pages using React.

I have tried to write some code on my own but i keep getting problems. I Created a route class for the class path, and 2 classes to move through. And the route class is imported to the app class. I am not pasting any data from the second class because its a written paragraph to be displayed.
This is what i have done:

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Firsttry from './firsttry' 
import Comp2 from "./comp2";

const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Firsttry} />
      <Route path="/comp2" component={Comp2} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default Routes;
```

Second class:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class Firsttry extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      redirect: false
    };
  }
  onclick = () => {
    this.setState({
      redirect: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/comp2" />;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <p> hello</p>
        <button onClick={this.onclick}>click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Firsttry;
```

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? Consider [accepting one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that’s the case.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the routes. May be always your first route is getting hit and Comp2 is never rendered.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/comp2' component={Comp2}  />
    <Route path='/'  component={Firsttry}/>
</Switch>
```

Or you have another option: adding exact prop to your route.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/'  component={Firsttry}/>        
  <Route exact path='/comp2' component={Comp2}  />
</Switch>
```

Comment: This, or add `exact` to the `Firsttry` route.

Comment: Yes.. Was about to edit it. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: No need to add exact to the 2nd route though

Comment: in case if we have <Route exact path='/comp2/:id' component={Comp2} also, adding exact would definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

Only one `Route` inside a `Switch` can be active at a time, and `/` will match every route. You can add the [`exact`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) prop to the `/` route to make sure it will only match on the root path.

```
const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Firsttry} />
      <Route path="/comp2" component={Comp2} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```